# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Increment Counter

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is it acceptable to increment a counter with a realtime database trigger using transaction?

```
exports.incPostCount = functions.database.ref('/threadsMeta/{threadId}/posts')
.onWrite(event => {
    admin.database().ref('/analytics/postCount')
    .transaction(count => {
        if (count === null) {
            return count = 1
        } else {
            return count + 1
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Definitely! In fact, that's exactly how it's done [in this code sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js), although with a few small differences:

```
exports.countlikechange = functions.database.ref("/posts/{postid}/likes/{likeid}").onWrite((event) => {
  var collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
  var countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('likes_count');

  return countRef.transaction(function(current) {
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return (current || 0) + 1;
    }
    else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return (current || 0) - 1;
    }
  });
});
```

Notably, this sample handles both an increment and a decrement case depending on whether the child node is being created or deleted.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: I recall reading somwhere that firebase might call some functions more than once. The same page strongly suggested writing idempotent functions. Is this safe?

Comment: If you depend on the number being 100% right 100% of the time, then yes you'll need to write the function idempotently. Sometimes off by a few isn't a problem, in which case this will be fine. You can also have a hybrid solution where you periodically run a script that will go through and "fix" any counts that are incorrect by reading the canonical data.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh For example when a posts gets deleted. The countlikechange get executed. How are you going to prevent that the countRef gets executed?